# Computing jacobian matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I want to calculate Jacobian matrix by Tensorflow.

What I have:

```
def compute_grads(fn, vars, data_num):
    grads = []
    for n in range(0, data_num):
        for v in vars:
            grads.append(tf.gradients(tf.slice(fn, [n, 0], [1, 1]), v)[0])
    return tf.reshape(tf.stack(grads), shape=[data_num, -1])
```

`fn` is a loss function, `vars` are all trainable variables, and `data_num` is a number of data.

But if we increase the number of data, it takes tremendous time to run the function `compute_grads`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you benchmarked your code? You can't improve it unless you know what you are trying to improve.

Comment: See [issue #675](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675) for a discussion about how to compute Jacobians in TensorFlow. In general, there is no "good way" to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I implemented Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm by following the issue, but the computational time was slower than ceres solver... which is implemented in c++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `X` and `Y` are Tensorflow tensors and that `Y` depends on `X`:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.parallel_for.gradients import jacobian
J=jacobian(Y,X)
```

The result has the shape `Y.shape + X.shape` and provides the partial derivative of each element of `Y` with respect to each element of `X`.

Comment: You mean Y.shape * X.shape ?

Comment: No. The + sign in this context is tuple concatenation (i.e., a1,a2..,an,b1,b2.,...,bn).

Comment: ... that is to say that the shape `(a,b)` mean `a*b` numbers and thus `(a,b)+(c,d)=(a,b,c,d)` means `a*b*c*d` numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Tensorflow 2 or Tensorflow <2 and Eager mode, you can use the GradientTape and the inbuild function:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
  x  = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0])
  g.watch(x)
  y = x * x
jacobian = g.jacobian(y, x)
# jacobian value is [[2., 0.], [0., 4.]]
```

Check the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#jacobian) for more